# Как проверить были ли сохранены данные в БД?

Tags: php, sqlite

есть уже код, но он выводит сообщения об успешном добавление, даже если в БД данные не были добавлены
как правильно проверить?

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

      error_reporting(1); // Отключение вывода стандартных сообщений об ошибках
      try {
               $sql = "INSERT INTO foo (title, category) VALUES('$title', '$category')";
               $db = new SQlite3("db.sqlite");
               $db->exec($sql);
               if($sql){
                    echo "Данные успешно сохранены!</br>";
                    echo $title;
               }
               else {
                    echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку.";
               }


      } catch (Exception $exception) { 
          echo "Произошла ошибка в строке ", $exception->getLine()-1, ": ", 
          $exception->getMessage();                       
      } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как-то странно проверяете успешность добавления, так как значение переменной `$sql` не меняется в процессе, там строка, она не пустая, потому `if ($sql)`, естественно, возвращает всегда `true`.

Попробуйте такой код:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foo (title, category) VALUES('$title', '$category')";
$db = new SQlite3("db.sqlite");

if($db->exec($sql)) {
    echo "Данные успешно сохранены!</br>";
    echo $title;
} else {
  echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку.";
}
```

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php) `SQlite3::exec` возвращает `false` в случае ошибки. Если ошибка была, то ее можно получить другим методом: [SQLite3::lastErrorMsg](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrormsg.php) (возвращает текстовое сообщение, поясняющее последнюю ошибку).

P.S. Совет, не относящийся к вопросу, применяйте [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), чтобы защититься от [инъекций](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection): [SQLite3::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проверить на пустоту значения, которые вы добавляете в самом начале, и, если они не пустые, то заносите их, а иначе `Exit`.